# Quiero exportar una hoja de Excel a Pdf con Python

Tags: python, excel, pdf

Soy nuevo en Python y tengo un archivo xlsx que deseo exportar a PDF, pero no he podido, quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar con este problema, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
from win32com import client
from pathlib import Path


file_name = 'RDT_Val_01.xlsx'
dir_path = Path('D://Programa Control de Obras - MySQL//BBDD/')
new_file_name = 'RDT_Val_01.pdf'
new_save_place = ('D://Programa Control de Obras - MySQL//BBDD//Archivos_PDF//')
path_and_place = new_save_place + new_file_name

print(path_and_place)

aplicacion = client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
aplicacion.Interactive = False
aplicacion.Visible = False



aplicacion = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
books = aplicacion.Workbooks.Open(dir_path / file_name)
print(books)

ws = books.WorkSheets[0]

#ws.Visible = 1

print(ws)

ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, path_and_place)
books.close()
```

y me arroja lo siguiente:

```
<COMObject Open>
<COMObject <unknown>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Programa Control de Obras - MySQL\xls_a_pdf.py", line 29, in <module>
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, path_and_place)
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 4, in ExportAsFixedFormat
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ocurrió una excepción.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Las dos primeras lineas son por los print() incluidos en el codigo. Estoy utilizando **Excel 2019**. Que puedo hacer para poder exportar el archivo xlsx a pdf, se los agradeceria si me pudieran ayudar. Saludos desde Zulia - Venezuela.

Comment: Prueba a cambiar ws = books.WorkSheets[0] (la primera hoja) por ws = books.Worksheets("Hoja1") e indica el nombre de la hoja, para ir viendo posibles causas

Comment: @pcandido está lleno de errores elementales, estoy armando una respuesta con la explicación pertinente y solución

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código tiene varios errores elementales.

Vamos por partes para que puedas entender que estaba mal:

1. Los caminos de las carpetas, en caso de Windows las barras son barras invertidas **** y se escriben dos debido a que una barra invertida declara carácter literal, así que dos barras invertidas significa que escribes una (un poco lioso).  Ejemplo:

   dir_path = 'D:\\Programa Control de Obras - MySQL\\BBDD\\'
2. Al encapsular un texto con Path('blablabla') lo transformas en un objeto de tipo path, pero las funciones de excel te piden tipo string (texto). (Nota que en el ejemplo anterior saque el PATH)
3. Para añadir un carácter y concatenar, hace falta que sean strings y usar el operador +, en el contexto que haces es equivalente a dividir entre strings "cosa imposible".

   No se pone:

   `dir_path / file_name`

   Si no:

   `dir_path+ '/'+ file_name`
4. Respecto a declarar dos veces `aplicacion = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")` desechas las anteriores configuraciones asignadas a este objeto (un objeto dentro de la variable).

Te dejo tu codigo comentado con las possibles correcciones:

```
from win32com import client
from pathlib import Path #no es necessario


file_name = 'RDT_Val_01.xlsx'
dir_path = Path('D://Programa Control de Obras - MySQL//BBDD/') #no se necessita el path y los // tiene que ser \\
new_file_name = 'RDT_Val_01.pdf'
new_save_place = ('D://Programa Control de Obras - MySQL//BBDD//Archivos_PDF//') # // tiene que ser \\ y el paréntesis sobra aunque no hace daño
path_and_place = new_save_place + new_file_name

print(path_and_place)

aplicacion = client.Dispatch('Excel.Application') # no sirve para nada debido a que lo declaras otra vez mas abajo
aplicacion.Interactive = False  # no sirve para nada debido a que lo declaras  el objeto otra vez que hace referncia abajo
aplicacion.Visible = False # no sirve para nada debido a que lo declaras  el objeto otra vez que hace referncia abajo



 aplicacion = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")  
 books = aplicacion.Workbooks.Open(dir_path / file_name) # mala concatenacion de strings
 print(books)

 ws = books.WorkSheets[0]

 #ws.Visible = 1

 print(ws)

 ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, path_and_place)
 books.close()
```

**Mi propuesta de código funcional:**

```
from win32com import client



file_name = 'RDT_Val_01.xlsx'
dir_path = 'D:\\Programa Control de Obras - MySQL\\BBDD\\'
new_file_name = 'RDT_Val_01.pdf'
new_save_place = ('D:\\Programa Control de Obras -MySQL\\BBDD\\Archivos_PDF\\')
path_and_place = new_save_place + new_file_name  #junto los dos strings
path_origin=dir_path + file_name #junto los dos strings
print(path_and_place)

aplicacion = client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
aplicacion.Interactive = False #marcamos que no sea interecionable (True para lo contrario)
aplicacion.Visible = False #marcamos que no sea visible (True para lo contrario)




books = aplicacion.Workbooks.Open() #abrimos el excel
print(books)

ws = books.WorkSheets[0]

#ws.Visible = 1 #no es necessario si marcas false que no vea el excel

print(ws) 

ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, path_and_place) #exportar a pdf
try: #claula para controlar el error si ya se ha cerrado

    books.close(False)  # si se tiene que cerrar no guardes los cambios
except:
    print("Ya cerrado") # avisar que ya estaba cerrado
```

**Recomendaciones**

- Aprender lo básico primero de Python. Recomiendo el siguiente orden:

  1. Tipos de datos que tiene Python(string,int,float,etc)
  2. Tipos de operadores matemáticos que hay en Python
  3. Conversiones de datos, mas los funciones para strings (concatenar,remplazar,etc.)
  4. Funciones
  5. Clases y objetos
  6. Modulos (como el win32com)
  7. Parte Grafica

Como ayudamemoria al empezar recomiendo [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/default.asp) (en inglés lo siento, pero es útil para buscar cuando no te acuerdas de algo)

- Poner comentarios de lo que se supone que tiene que hacer ideal para cuando aún no te lo sabes de memoria (los comentarios se marcan al principio con #)
- Recomiendo que si no sabes las bases del lenguaje, no uses ChatGPT. Si usas ChatGPT cogerlo con pinzas, ya que el código puede no funcionar o puede hacerlo incorrectamente. El Chatgpt es útil para hacer un esquema o esqueleto como un borrador de una idea nada más.

Saludos,

Comment: Muchas gracias, por tu aporte. Saludos. Tomare encuenta la pagina  w3schools para aprender.

Comment: Solo por si acaso: creería que es mejor decir _ayudamemoria_ que _chuleta_. De mi parte entiendo el significado (en otros lugares lo llaman _copiatín_, _acordeón_, _machete_...) pero puede que otros no entiendan el contexto de la palabra.

Comment: Si te ha servido para solucionarlo, marca la respuesta como aceptada, lo mismo con las otras 2 preguntas que has hecho.

Comment: @padaleiana mea culpa, lo cambio, gracias por el aporte